# Python breaks string in check_command

Tags: android, python, batch-file

I'm working on a white label android app, which I've been building through cmd on windows. I need to transfer these commands to python so this is what I came up with:

Old command was in a Batch file:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file="**${FILELOCATION}"
-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password="${PASSWORD}"
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias="${SLUG}"
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password="${PASSWORD}"
```

This is what i translated this too in Python 2.7:

```
  check_call([GRADLEW, ':app:assembleRelease' +
                    ' -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file="{}"'.format(key_info['file']) +
                    ' -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password="{}"'.format(key_info['store_pw']) +
                    ' -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias="{}"'.format(key_info['alias']) +
                    ' -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password="{}"'.format(key_info['key_pw'])],
                   cwd=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app'))
```

This results in the following error:

> Command '['C:\Data\****\gradlew.bat', ':app:assembleRelease
>   -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file="C:\Data\****.keystore" -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password="****" -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias="****" -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password="****"']' returned non-zero exit status 1

This is the gradle error i get when running this command:

> - What went wrong:
>     Project 'assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file="C' not found in project ':app'.

However, when i copy and paste the output from this python script and run it through the android studio terminal and CMD, it works just fine. So it looks like python is somehow cutting off my key_info['file'] string at the colon. What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when there's space in the arguments, `subprocess.call` adds quotes, which is not what you want (the second element of the list is seen as one sole argument, ouch!)

I would tokenize the arguments manually instead of concatenating them with spaces, which is much cleaner and portable:

```
call([GRADLEW,':app:assembleRelease',
    '-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file="{}"'.format(key_info['file']),
    '-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password="{}"'.format(key_info['store_pw']),
    '-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias="{}"'.format(key_info['alias']),
    '-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password="{}"'.format(key_info['key_pw'])],
    cwd=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app'))
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks :) Will accept your answer in 8 minutes, you're too fast for me to be able to accept it.